# How to join only specific fileds from rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, where-clause

I am wondering if there is a way to join only those rows, that have have columns slider set to 0 in my query. Right now it looks like

```
    $db->queryCache('SELECT ' . $objectFields . ' FROM people o
LEFT JOIN zdjecia z ON z.obiekt=o.id
LEFT JOIN obkat ON obkat.obiekt=o.id
WHERE o.ac=1
GROUP BY o.id
ORDER BY priorytet DESC', array(
    'people',
    'obkat',
    'zdjecia'
), 3600);
```

I wish to join only those rows from `zdjecia` that have column `canUse` set to `1`

I tried:

```
    $db->queryCache('SELECT ' . $objectFields . ' FROM people o
LEFT JOIN zdjecia z ON z.obiekt=o.id
LEFT JOIN obkat ON obkat.obiekt=o.id
WHERE o.ac=1 AND z.canUse=1
GROUP BY o.id
ORDER BY priorytet DESC', array(
    'people',
    'obkat',
    'zdjecia'
), 3600);
```

but that did not help. What is a proper way to join only certain rows from table in query like this one?

Thanks!

Comment: `'zdjecia' WHERE z.canUse = 1`

Comment: `but that did not help` Are you facing any error? Or unexpected result?

Comment: You could add the clause directly to your join clause, i.e. `LEFT JOIN zdjecia z ON z.obiekt=o.id AND z.canUse=1`.

Comment: The second query works, but the items from z are not filtered

Comment: @SamuelRenold - Thanks! that works just fine! :)